# Django app not loading with DisallowedHost error even after adding IP to ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I'm facing an issue with my Django web application deployment on an Amazon EC2 instance. The app is running using Gunicorn and Nginx as a reverse proxy. However, when I try to access the app using the public IP address (ipaddress:8000), it's not loading, and I keep getting a "DisallowedHost" error.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

In my Django settings.py, I've added the public IP address to the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting:
python
Copy code
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['ipaddress:8000']
I've confirmed that Gunicorn is running and bound to ipaddress:8000 .

Nginx is configured as a reverse proxy with the following settings:

nginx
Copy code
server {
listen 80;
server_name ipaddress:8000

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://ipaddress:8000 
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

}
Despite these configurations, the app still does not load, and I receive the following error in my Django logs:

css
Copy code
[2023-08-02 17:28:00 +0000] [#] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-08-02 17:28:00 +0000] [#] [INFO] Listening at: http://ipaddress:8000 (#)
...
DisallowedHost at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'ip address'. You may need to add 'ipaddress' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
It seems like Django is still considering the request host as 'ipaddress', even though I've explicitly added it to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Any suggestions on what could be causing this issue and how to resolve it? Is there anything I'm missing in my configuration?

Thank you for your help!

everything above I have tried